# PHP - Get input from dynamically added html table rows

Tags: php

I have the following Fiddle set up here [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqugd7vL/7/)

As you can see, I am able to add inputs by clicking the Add Row button.

All inputs that are added have a unique id and name. The problem is, I cant just do something like

```
$actionInput = $_POST["actionInput"];
```

Because I might need

```
 $actionInput1 = $_POST["actionInput1"]; 
 $actionInput2 = $_POST["actionInput2"]; 
 $actionInput3 = $_POST["actionInput3"];
```

Depending on how many rows are added.  So how can I get all the inputs without knowing what inputs I need to grab?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you need to maintain counter in hidden, which you will get at the time of posting the form in case you don't want to maintain elements as array, otherwise you can put elements as array as described below:

```
<input type=text name="inputs[]" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Name your inputs with array boundary, like:

```
<input type=text name="actioninput[]" />
```

now you can itreate throught them in you POST or GET ( depends ) array:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Answer (score 1):

replace `name=actionInput` with `name=actionInput[]`
it should be an array with same name
same thing will apply with all form fields generated dynamically whose values you'll need.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your JSFiddle works fine for you, following are the steps.

1) Get keys of `$_POST`.

2) Get maximum counter value from keys.

3) Take a for loop from `0` to `count of post`.

4) If counter is `0`, no suffix, else, add counter as suffix.

5) Now, you get posted variable.

6) Repeat it for every element in rows.

```
<?php
$keys = array_keys($_POST);
$keys = implode(',', $keys);
$n = str_replace('actionInput', '', $keys);
$m = explode(',', $n);
$max = max($m);

for ($i=0 ; $i<=$max ; $i++) {
    $suffix = ($i==0) ? '' : $i;
    if (isset($_POST['actionInput' . $suffix])) {
        echo "<br/>-".$_POST['actionInput' . $suffix];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not what I would recommend.   This data is better handled as POST subarrays.

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in Add row jquery event 
**return name + i to return name**

Remove i from it and then
name=actionInput[]

print_r($_POST);

It will gives array of actioninput